# Sqlite - automatic deletion from multiple tables

Tags: sqlite

I suppose it's already answered, but I tried to formulate my search phrases in various ways and failed to find an answer.

I have an SQLite database, where one of the tables is named Student. Suppose that one of the students, let's say Peter, also appears in multiple other tables "relations", like "likes to eat ..", "has courses ...", "lives in ..". Please note that those are separate tables with their own columns. So, let's say, Peter appears in 100 tables.

Now, I want to delete student Peter. I delete him from Student table, but his name in the other 99 tables is still hanging, whereas I want it to disappear from those tables as well.

**The question:** is there a way in SQLite to do such a deletion automatically? In a described case, do I have to manually delete Peter from all 100 tables "by hand", or can SQLite track those deletes and automatically delete Peter from the other 99 tables if he is deleted from Students? Maybe via a "foreign key" or something like this..
Another way of formulating the question: I added Peter to Students, now is it possible to add Peter to another tables in such a way that if he's deleted from Student he will be deleted from the other tables as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need foreign key with `on delete cascade` action.
A qiuck lookup for sqlite doc i've found this:
https://sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html

see section 4.3

Comment: Thank you! I'm pretty new to SQL/SQLite, but I suspected it has something to do with foreign keys, well now I have a direction to look for information in.